# Smooth sequence of functions converging pointwise to a smooth function and limit of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

In the wikipedia page of uniform convergence, it says that given a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ of differentiable real functions (say, over the reals) with the property that it converges pointwise to some function $f$, the limit of $\{f_{n}' \}$ need not be equal to $f'$.

It then gives an example where $\{ f_n \} $ converges uniformly to a differentiable $f$, but $\{f_n '\}$ does not converge even pointwise.

My question is, what if we assume that each $f_n$ and their limit $f$ are, say, $C^\infty$, and $\{ f_n '\}$ converges pointwise to some $C^\infty$ function $g$ as well. Is it now enough to show that $f' = g$? Or do we further need to assume uniform convergence? Is there a classic counterexample to this question as well?

Comment: Intersting question! The answer is yes *if* you know also that $|f_n'|\leq M$ for some constant independent of $n$. I'm not sure right now about the general case.

Comment: @Jose27 Oh right, that's like a special case of dominated convergence?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Of course, you can get away with a weaker condition like $|f_n'|\leq  h$ for some integrable function $h$, but it's still not enough to give the general case unfortunately.

Comment: @Jose27 So this could mean it is likely there is a counterexample obtained from a sequence not satisfying the criteria for dominated convergence.

Comment: It also looks like this should be useful, then we can reduce to taking integrals over compact intervals: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100416/limit-of-sequence-of-differentiable-functions-and-sequence-of-derivatives

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions from
${\mathbb R}$ to ${\mathbb R}$.

Let $f,g$ be two more $C^\infty$ functions from ${\mathbb R}$ to ${\mathbb R}$.

Assume, as $i\to\infty$, $f_i\to f$ pointwise.

Assume, as $i\to\infty$, $f'_i\to g$ pointwise.

We wish to show: $f'=g$.

Define $G:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ by:
$\forall x\in{\mathbb R}$, $G(x)=\int_0^x\,g$.
Then $G$ is $C^\infty$ and $G'=g$.

For all integers $i>0$, let $\phi_i:=f_i-G$; then $\phi_i$ is $C^\infty$.

Also, $\forall$integers $i>0$, we have: $\phi'_i=f'_i-g$.

Let $\phi:=f-G$; then $\phi$ is $C^\infty$.
Also, we have: $\phi'=f'-g$.

Also, as $i\to\infty$, $\phi_i\to\phi$ pointwise.
Also, $\phi'_i\to0$ pointwise.

It suffices to show: $\phi'=0$.

Given $a\in{\mathbb R}$, we wish to show that $\phi'(a)=0$.
Assume $\phi'(a)\ne0$. Want: Contradiction.

Let $\varepsilon:=|\phi'(a)|/2$.
Then $|\phi'(a)|>\varepsilon>0$.

By continuity of $\phi'$, choose $\delta>0$ s.t.,
on $[a-\delta,a+\delta]$, $|\phi'|>\varepsilon$.

Let $K:=[a-\delta,a+\delta]$.
Then, on $K$, $|\phi'|>\varepsilon$.

For all integers $n>0$, let
$$C_n:=\{x\in K~\hbox{s.t.}~\forall\hbox{integers }i\ge
n,\,|\phi'_i(x)|\le\varepsilon\};$$
then $C_n$ is closed in ${\mathbb R}$ and $C_n\subseteq K$.

Because $\phi'_i\to0$ pointwise, we get: $C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\cup\cdots=K$.

By the Baire Category Theorem, choose an integer $n>0$ s.t.: the
interior in ${\mathbb R}$ of $C_n$ is nonempty.

Choose $q$ in the interior in ${\mathbb R}$ of $C_n$.
Choose $\rho>0$ s.t. $[q-\rho,q+\rho]\subseteq C_n$.

Let $J:=[q-\rho,q+\rho]$. Then $J\subseteq C_n$.

By definition of $C_n$, $\forall$integers $i\ge n$, we have: on $C_n$,
$|\phi'_i|\le\varepsilon$.

Therefore, $\forall$integers $i\ge n$, we have: on $J$,
$|\phi'_i|\le\varepsilon$.

Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, $\forall$integers $i\ge n$,
$\forall$distinct $a,b\in J$,
$$\left|\frac{\phi_i(b)-\phi_i(a)}{b-a}\right|\le\varepsilon.$$
Taking the limit, as $i\to\infty$, we get:
$\forall$distinct $a,b\in J$,
$$\left|\frac{\phi(b)-\phi(a)}{b-a}\right|\le\varepsilon.$$
So, since $q\in J$, we get:
$\forall b\in J\backslash\{q\}$,
$$\left|\frac{\phi(b)-\phi(q)}{b-q}\right|\le\varepsilon.$$
Letting $b\to q$, we get: $|\phi'(q)|\le\varepsilon$.

Recall: on $K$, $|\phi'|>\varepsilon$.
So, since $q\in J\subseteq C_n\subseteq K$,
we get $|\phi'(q)|>\varepsilon$.

Contradiction. QED

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Thanks for the excellent answer

Comment: After defining $C_n$, you wrote: "Since $ \phi_i \to 0$ pointwise," when you meant "Since $ \phi'_i \to 0$ pointwise,"

Comment: I presume that the same argument works for multivariable cases as well?

Comment: I suppose one natural generalization would be to have a fixed $C^\infty$ vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$, and a sequence $f_1,f_2,\ldots:M\to{\mathbb R}$ of $C^\infty$ functions, along with two more $C^\infty$ functions $f:M\to{\mathbb R}$ and $g:M\to{\mathbb R}$. Assume $f_i\to f$ pointwise on $M$ as $i\to\infty$. Assume $Xf_i\to g$ pointwise on $M$. Then $Xf=g$ on $M$. Is this the kind of thing you have in mind? I do think this should be true. If it were to fail at a point $p\in M$, then, using an integral curve for $X$ through $p$, it seems to me that we'd contradict the main result.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for pointing out a typo, Yuval. I corrected it.

Trying to minimize hypotheses, in the proof, I came up with:

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ be a sequence of
functions all differentiable on ${\mathbb R}$. Assume that the
pointwise limit $f$ of $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ exists everywhere on
${\mathbb R}$ and is continuously differentiable on ${\mathbb R}$,
and that the
pointwise limit $g$ of $f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$ exists everywhere on
${\mathbb R}$ and is continuous on ${\mathbb R}$.
Then $f'=g$.

Three comments:

---

**First**, if we remove the hypothesis of continuity of $g$, we get a
counterexample, as follows.

Define $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ by:
$\forall$integers $k\ge1$, $\forall x\in{\mathbb R}$,
$f_k(x)=xe^{-kx^2}$.

Then the pointwise (or, even, uniform) limit $f$ of $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ is the
constant function $0$ on ${\mathbb R}$.

However, the pointwise limit $g$ of $f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$
is equal to $1$ at $0$, and is equal to $0$ on ${\mathbb R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Then $f'=g$ fails to be true at $0$.

---

**Second**, we might only assume that $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ converges
pointwise to a continuous limit $f$, keeping the hypothesis that
$f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$ converges pointwise to a continuous limit $g$, and then
hope to prove continuous differentiability everywhere on ${\mathbb R}$ of $f$.
If we could prove such a result, then the theorem above would give: $f'=g$.

However, we get a counterexample, as follows.

Let $J:=[0,1]$.

Let $U_1:=(1/3,2/3)$.

Let $U_2:=(1/9,2/9)\cup(7/9,8/9)$.

Let $U_3:=(1/27,2/27)\cup(7/27,8/27)\cup(19/27,20/27)\cup(25/27,26/27)$.

etc.

For any integer $k\ge1$, to go from $U_k$ to $U_{k+1}$,
write $J\backslash(U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_k)$ as a finite union
of $2^k$ compact intervals, and let $U_{k+1}$ be the union of the
"open middle thirds" of each of those compact intervals.

Then $U_1,U_2,U_3,\ldots$ are pairwise-disjoint.

The Cantor set is $C:=J\backslash(U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3\cup\cdots)$.
Let $\phi$ be the Cantor function.
Then $\phi:J\to{\mathbb R}$ is continuous and
$\phi'=0$ on $U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3\cup\cdots$ and $\phi(0)=0$
and $\phi(1)=1$.

For each integer $k\ge1$, let $f_k:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ be
a $C^\infty$ function s.t. $f_k(0)=0$ and s.t. $f_k(1)=1$ and
s.t. $f_k=\phi$ on $U_k$ and
s.t. $\{x\in{\mathbb R}\,|\,f'_k(x)\ne0\}\subseteq U_{k+1}$ and
s.t. $f'_k\ge0$ on ${\mathbb R}$.

Then, because $U_2,U_3,U_4,\ldots$ are pairwise-disjoint,
it follows, $\forall x\in{\mathbb R}$, that there is at most
one integer $k\ge1$ s.t. $x\in U_{k+1}$.
Then, $\forall x\in{\mathbb R}$, there is at most
one integer $k\ge1$ s.t. $f'_k(x)\ne0$.
Then the pointwise limit $g$ of $f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$ is
the constant function $0$ on ${\mathbb R}$.

The pointwise (or, even, uniform) limit $f$ of $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ is
$0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and is $1$ on $(1,\infty)$ and is $\phi$ on $J$.
Then $f$ is continuous everywhere on ${\mathbb R}$.
Also, $f$ does not have finite derivative
at any point of the Cantor set $C$.

In particular, we see that $f'=g$ fails to be true at any point of $C$.

---

**Third**, we might only assume that $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ converges
pointwise to a differentiable limit $f$, keeping the hypothesis that
$f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$ converges pointwise to a continuous limit $g$, and then
hope to prove continuous differentiability everywhere on ${\mathbb R}$ of $f$.
If we could prove such a result, then the theorem above would give: $f'=g$.

A counterexample to this is similar to the one in the **second**
comment, but relies on a lot of machinery for finding complicated
derivatives. A standard reference for this machinery is Andrew
Bruckner's book, "Differentiation of Real Functions". (The Pompeiu
derivative is already somewhat difficult, and I sometimes refer to
these more complicated methods as "Pompeiu on steroids"!)

The $f$ in the counterexample described below is differentiable and
satisfies both $f'\ge0$ on ${\mathbb R}$ and $f'$ is bounded on
${\mathbb R}$.

Let $A:=(-\infty,0]$. Let $J:=[0,1]$. Let $B:=[1,\infty)$.

By forming a sufficiently fat Cantor set, and letting $\phi$ be the
Cantor function of that set, we
can guarantee that $\phi:J\to{\mathbb R}$ is Lipschitz.
((Proof: Choose a sequence $\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3,\ldots$ of positive real numbers
such that $\eta_1+\eta_2+\eta_3+\cdots<\infty$.
Start with the identity function on $J$. It is Lipschitz-$1$.
Identify a very small middle interval inside of $J$.
This splits $J$ into three intervals;
there are now two larger intervals separated by one very small middle interval.
The new Cantor approximation function is constant on the very small interval
and slightly steeper than Lipschitz-$1$ on the other two.
By making the middle interval small enough,
the new function is Lipschitz-$(1+\eta_1)$.
Now identify very, very small middle intervals
inside each of the two larger intervals.
Take care that the new Cantor approximation function is
Lipschitz-$(1+\eta_1+\eta_2)$. Continue.))

We have: $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$.
Then $\phi$ is nonconstant. Also, $\phi$ is semi-increasing.

Choose pairwise-disjoint closed intervals $I_1,I_2,I_3,\ldots\subseteq(0,1)$
all of positive length
s.t., $\forall$integers $k\ge1$,
$\phi$ is constant on $I_k$
and s.t. $I_1\cup I_2\cup I_3\cup\cdots$
is dense in $J$.

Extend $\phi$ to a function
$\psi:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ satsifying
$\psi=0$ on $A$, $\psi=\phi$ on $J$, $\psi=1$ on $B$.
Then $\psi$ is Lipschitz.
Also, $\forall$integer $k\ge1$, we have:
$\psi$ is constant on $I_k$.
Also, $\psi$ is constant on $A$.
Also, $\psi$ is constant on $B$.
Also, $\psi$ is nonconstant. Also, $\psi$ is semi-increasing.
Also, $A\cup B\cup I_1\cup I_2\cup I_3\cup\cdots$
is dense in ${\mathbb R}$.

Let $Z$ be the set of points where $\psi$ is not differentiable. Since
$\psi$ is Lipschitz, we conclude that $Z$ is a null set, i.e., a set
of Lebesgue measure $0$.
Also, $\psi'$ is defined and bounded on ${\mathbb R}\backslash Z$.

Since $\phi$ is Lipschitz, it carries null
sets to null sets. Then the image $Y:=\psi(Z)$ of $Z$ under $\psi$ is null.
Also, $\forall x\in Z$, we have $\psi(x)\in Y$.

Combining Theorem 5.5(a) and Theorem 6.5 in Chapter 2 of Andrew
Bruckner's book, "Differentiation of Real Functions", we see that, for
any null subset $X$ of ${\mathbb R}$, there exists a
strictly-increasing, differentiable function $\rho:{\mathbb
R}\to{\mathbb R}$ s.t. $\rho'=0$ on $X$ and such that $\rho'$ is
bounded.
((Proof: Let $X'\subseteq{\mathbb R}$ be a null $G_\delta$
such that $X\subseteq X'$.
Then apply Theorem 6.5 with
$E:={\mathbb R}\backslash X'$.
Repace "$f$" in Theorem 6.5 with "$\lambda$"
to avoid confusion with our "$f$" defined below.
Then $\lambda=0$ on $X'$ and $\lambda>0$ on ${\mathbb R}\backslash X'$.
By Theorem 5.5(a),
choose a differentiable function
$\rho:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ s.t.
$\rho'$ is bounded and s.t. $\rho'=\lambda$.
Then $\rho'=0$ on $X'$ and $\rho'>0$ on ${\mathbb R}\backslash X'$.
Then $\rho$ is semi-increasing.
A function that is semi-increasing but not strictly-increasing
must be constant on a nonempty open interval.
Since $X'$ is null and
since $\rho'>0$ on ${\mathbb R}\backslash X'$,
we see that $\rho$ is not constant on any nonempty open interval.
Then $\rho$ is strictly-increasing.
Since $X\subseteq X'$ and since $\rho'=0$ on $X'$,
we see that $\rho'=0$ on $X$.))

Applying this to $Y$, choose a strictly-increasing, differentiable
function $\rho:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ s.t. $\rho'=0$ on $Y$ and
s.t. $\rho'$ is bounded.

Since $\rho$ is strictly-increasing and since $\psi$ is nonconstant,
we get: $\rho\circ\psi$ is nonconstant.

Since $\rho$ is strictly-increasing and since $\psi$ is semi-increasing,
we get: $\rho\circ\psi$ is semi-increasing.

Since $\psi$ is constant on each of: $A,B,I_1,I_2,I_3,\ldots$,
we get: $\rho\circ\psi$ is constant on each of those same sets.

For all $x\in{\mathbb R}\backslash Z$, since $\psi$ is differentiable
at $x$ and since $\rho$ is differentiable at $\psi(x)$, we get:
$\rho\circ\psi$ is differentiable at $x$ and
$(\rho\circ\psi)'(x)=(\rho'(\psi(x))\cdot(\psi'(x))$.
So, since $\psi'$ is defined and bounded
on ${\mathbb R}\backslash Z$
and since $\rho'$ is defined and bounded on ${\mathbb R}$,
it follows that $(\rho\circ\psi)'$ is
defined and bounded on ${\mathbb R}\backslash Z$.
That is, $\rho\circ\psi$ is differentiable on ${\mathbb R}\backslash Z$
and that $(\rho\circ\psi)'$ is bounded on ${\mathbb R}\backslash Z$.

For all $x\in Z$, we have $\psi(x)\in Y$, so $\rho'(\psi(x))=0$.
For all $x\in Z$, since $\psi$ is Lipschitz and since
$\rho'(\psi(x))=0$, it is a basic real-analysis exercise to show:
$\rho\circ\psi$ is differentiable at $x$
and $(\rho\circ\psi)'(x)=0$.
Then $\rho\circ\psi$ is differentiable on $Z$
and $(\rho\circ\psi)'$ is bounded on $Z$.

By the preceding two paragraphs, we get: $\rho\circ\psi$ is differentiable and $(\rho\circ\psi)'$ is bounded.

Let $f:=\rho\circ\psi$. Then $f$ is differentiable.
Also, $f$ is semi-increasing. Also, $f'$ is bounded.
Also, $\forall$integer $k\ge1$,
$f$ is constant on $I_k$.
Also, $f$ is constant on $A$.
Also, $f$ is constant on $B$.
Also, $f$ is nonconstant.

Recall that
$A\cup B\cup I_1\cup I_2\cup I_3\cup\cdots$ is dense in ${\mathbb R}$.

For each integer $k\ge1$, choose a semi-increasing
$C^\infty$ function $f_k:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$
s.t. $f_k=f$ on $A\cup B\cup I_1\cup\cdots\cup I_j$
and s.t. $\{x\in{\mathbb R}\,|\,f'_k(x)\ne0\}\subseteq
I_{k+1}\cup I_{k+2}\cup I_{k+3}\cup\cdots$.

Then the pointwise limit $g$ of
$f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,\ldots$ is
the constant function $0$ on ${\mathbb R}$.

Also, the pointwise (or, even, uniform) limit of $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ is $f$.

Since $f$ is nonconstant and $g$ is identically zero, we see that
$f'=g$ fails to be true.

Comment: Thank you so much for the many counterexamples! This answers quite a few questions I had about these as well